# Quarantine line at the Mississippi

Tags: society

Could the US military, with the help of local and Federal Law Enforcement, enact and enforce a quarantine line at the Mississippi River? Like in the example of a second Spanish flu outbreak, could they block Bridges and highways, ferries etc, I know the Mississippi is pretty small towards Lake Superior, buy maybe fences erected along the roadways?  Working on a novel idea, where a group of people is stuck in the "wild" outside of the quarantine zone east of the Mississippi.

Comment: Side note, the western side of the Mississippi is drastically more "wild" than the east side, even when you count Southern California. Might make more sense to flip it.

Answer (score 3):

While blocking or dropping bridges, stopping ferry traffic etc. would have some effect, the primary issue is the sheer size of the area to be covered. There are simply not enough personnel to patrol the entire length of the Mississippi river, so the quarantine would constantly "leak" as people swam the river, or crossed on canoes, rafts and small boats. They could also cast off from the east coast or Florida and cross the Gulf of Mexico to land west of New Orleans, or walk ito Canada and across.

Without more details, we don't even know how much effort the USG might be putting into this project. Are we talking about an apocalyptic, world ending virus? In that case, *nuking* everything east of the Mississippi river might be justified. For lesser levels of awful, maybe the border patrol gets complacent or is willing to accept bribes to let people through.

As well, there will be two way traffic. Doctors and scientists will be going into the quarantine zone to take samples and do studies. Salvage teams might need to go in and recover industrial machinery, corporate records and government archives. There might also be testing stations where people are screened and those who are clear are airlifted back to the safe zone.

So think about the details a bit more, and then the issues of the story will become clear.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no due to the works put in place by the US Army Corps of Engineers.

## Corps of Engineers

The Mississippi River is one of the largest rivers in the world; but it is undoubtedly the most well managed. The Corps of Engineers Mississippi Division has a LOT of locks and dams on the river; [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_locks_and_dams_of_the_Upper_Mississippi_River) is a list from the source to St. Louis. Here is map of the riverway broken into its even relief sections:

[image]

As you can see, the river is more like a series of pools (28 above St. Louis, more below) nowadays. That means that the river is relatively easy to swim across. With thousands of miles of river that can be easily swum across, it wont be easy to stop cross river traffic. Even worse, a large but variable portion of the upper river freezes solid every winter; in 1889 it froze all the way to the Gulf of Mexico.

Until ALL the locks and dams on the river are destroyed, the river will be easy to cross. But the millions of people on the left bank of the river would probably not be super cool with the floods that would cause.

Answer (score 1):

They could try, but they would probably fail. This border would be longer than the U.S.-Mexico border and would be in much more habitable territory so there wouldn't be a natural desert barrier for most of it. It also doesn't take much of a boat to cross.

A somewhat similar concept is explored in the book "The Water Knife" by Paolo Bacigalupi, set in the near future of the American Southwest, in which U.S. states exist and are subject to the federal courts but are allowed (or at least not prevented from) establishing border controls as refugees flee from places that droughts have made uninhabitable to neighboring states, enforced with volunteer militias supported by state governments or various water authorities.

The trouble with a quarantine line that big is that even a 99.99% successful barrier would not be enough to prevent a disease from spreading because the contagion of the 0.01% of attempts that make it past the line would be enough to render the entire effort more or less futile.

Another literary precedent is "Red Moon" by Benjamin Percy, in which part of the United States becomes controlled by werewolves in a scenario a bit like the one envisioned by the anti-mutant political movement in the X-Men universe.